# Создание слота в своем классе

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

В рамках задачи необходимо по нажатию кнопки (`QPushButton`) добавлять соответствующий символ в строку. Реализуется некоторое подобие авторизации пользователя. Для этого написан такой класс:

```
struct PStr:public QObject {
private:
  std::string pass = "1234";
  std::string input;
public slots:
  void action(char c, QMainWindow * w)
  {
    input += c;
    if (input == pass)
    {
        w->hide();
    }
  }
};
```

При вызове `QObject::connect(button1, SIGNAL(clicked()), p, SLOT(action('1', w)));`, где PStr * p, компилируется, но выдает ошибки в консоль при запуске:
`QObject::connect: No such slot QObject::action('1', w)`

---

Кто-то мельком и не подробно посоветовал указать конструктор, вынести определение метода и добавить Q_OBJECT, но тут я завис:

```
class PStr:public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public slots:
  void action(char c, QMainWindow * w);
public:
  PStr() {
    
  }
};

void PStr::action(char c, QMainWindow * w)
{
  std::string pass = "1234";
  std::string input;
  input += c;
  if (input == pass)
  {
      w->hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: объявление `PStr` находится в хедере или в файле реализации? и к делу не относится, но конструктор обычно принимает родительский объект в качестве параметра...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. макрос Q_OBJECT обязателен для рутин самого кьюта, чтобы при уничтожении вашего объекта он отключался от связанных с ним сигналов, освобождалась память и т.п..
2. Вы соединяете несоединяемое (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots-with-default-arguments) ваш сигнал не имеет аргументов (`void`), в то время как слот ожидает (`char, QMainWindow*`), чтобы такое соединить предложу использовать лямбду

`QObject::connect(button1, &QPushButton::clicked, p, [=](){ p->action('1', w); });`

Писал по памяти, мог ошибиться с синтаксисом